# How do I insert the values in askdirectory into entry? Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to get the directory path into the entry field in Te

Gui File

```
    self.btn_browseOne = tk.Button(self.master,width=13, height=2, text='Browse...', command=lambda:func.getDir())
```

func File

```
def getDir():
getPath = filedialog.askdirectory()
txt_browseEntryOn.insert(0,getPath)
return getPath


if __name__=="__main__":
    pass
```

Comment: Is txt_browseEntryOn in a class? you use `self.` for your button so I am assuming the entry is also in a class.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I just and it can't find it somehow

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog as fd
root = Tk()
entry1 = ttk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()
def getDirPath():
    z = fd.askdirectory()
    entry1.insert(END,z)
b1 = ttk.Button(root,text="ok",command=getDirPath)

b1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```